# definition of free product of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I encountered this definition of free product in Munkres Topology:
[image]
It is a bit unclear to me that the free product of 2 copies of $G$ is different from the free product of 3 copies of $G$. In particular, does $ G \star G \star G $ contain more element than $ G \star G $?.

Say, if $a,b,c \in G$, then $abc$ belong to both groups, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$abc$ belongs to both groups only if you're sloppy with your notation. The free product is invariant under replacing each factor with an isomorphic copy of itself; so just relabel the elements of $G$ to obtain an isomorphic group $H$ and a third isomorphic group $J$, with $G, H, J$ pairwise disjoint as sets. Then given a word $abc$, there is precisely one way it could have been formed, depending on whether $a$, $b$, and $c$ are in some or all of $G$, $H$, or $J$. (In fact, Munkres says this: "Suppose that $G_{\alpha} \cap G_{\beta}$ consists of the identity element alone whenever $\alpha \not = \beta$".)

Example: if $G = \{e_G, a, b\}$ then let $H = \{e_H, c, d\}$ and $J = \{e_J, x, y\}$. Then the word $abx$ can *only* have been made using the letter $a$ from $G$, the letter $b$ from $G$, and the letter $x$ from $J$.

Comment: If $G_1, G_2, G_3$ are cyclic groups generated by 1 element, say, $ G_1 = \langle a \rangle $, $ G_2 = \langle b \rangle $, $ G_3 = \langle c \rangle $. Intuitively, $G_1$ is not isomorphic to $G_2 \star G_3$, but what would be the formal argument to prove this?

Comment: @marcelnguyen The former is cyclic; the latter is not even abelian.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have realized that. But how would you show $2$ isomorphic copies of $G=\langle g \rangle$ is not isomorphic to $3$ isomorphic copies of $G$? Both are non-abelian I suppose.

Comment: You can probably ignore the following sentence if you don't like it. The coproduct (union) of $n$ copies of $\{1\}$ is $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$; since left adjoints preserve colimits, and the free-group functor is a left-adjoint, we have $F_1*\dots*F_1 \cong F_n$ where $F_i$ is the free group on $i$ generators. So you're asking if $F_2 \cong F_3$. But $F_X \cong F_Y$ iff $X$ and $Y$ are in bijection. I can prove that if you need it - it involves a cunning idea (consider the quotient group $G/S_G$ where $G$ is $F_X$, $S_G = \langle g^2: g \in G \rangle$, as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$).